# multiple column layout inside a tabPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I generate a lot of input using `renderUI`, I would like to have a multicolumn display inside a tabPanel.

Of course the number of input is dynamic :-)

Any idea how do do this ?

```
   library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot",
uiOutput("lot_of_input")
        ),
        tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$lot_of_input <- renderUI({
list( 
  numericInput(inputId = "A","A",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "AB","AB",1),numericInput(inputId = "B","C",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "C2","C",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "A3","A",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "AB3","AB",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "B3","C",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "C23","C",1)#, lot of other input
) # In my code this list is returned by a function
  })

  output$summary <- renderText("coucou")
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**not this :**
[image: not this]

**but this :**
[image: but this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split your list in 2 with `split`, you can `sort` `f` argument in `split` if order matter :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot",
                 uiOutput("lot_of_input")
        ),
        tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$lot_of_input <- renderUI({
    x <- list( 
      numericInput(inputId = "A","A",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "AB","AB",1),numericInput(inputId = "B","C",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "C2","C",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "A3","A",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "AB3","AB",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "B3","C",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "C23","C",1),
      numericInput(inputId = "C24","C",1)
    ) 
    fluidRow(
      lapply(
        X = split(x, f = rep(c(1, 2), length.out = length(x))),
        FUN = column, width = 6
      )
    )
  })

  output$summary <- renderText("coucou")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a data manipulation problem, so here is one option using `dplyr` :

```
pack <- function( inputs, nc = 4){
  n <- length(inputs)
  nrows <- ceiling( n / nc )

  tibble( 
    row = head( rep(1:nrows, each = nc), n ), 
    inputs = inputs
  ) %>% 
    group_by(row) %>% 
    summarise( list(do.call(splitLayout, inputs)) ) %>% 
    pull() 

}
```

which you then use in your output:

```
output$lot_of_input <- renderUI({
  inputs <- list( 
    numericInput(inputId = "A","A",1),
    numericInput(inputId = "AB","AB",1),
    numericInput(inputId = "B","C",1),
    numericInput(inputId = "C2","C",1),
    numericInput(inputId = "A3","A",1),
    numericInput(inputId = "AB3","AB",1),
    numericInput(inputId = "B3","C",1),
    numericInput(inputId = "C23","C",1)#, lot of other input
  ) 

  pack( inputs, 4 )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`fluidRow` and `column` should arrange it accordingly as shown below:

```
list(
          fluidRow(
            column(3,
                   numericInput(inputId = "A","A",1)),
            column(3,
                   numericInput(inputId = "C2","C",1))
          ),

          fluidRow(
            column(3,
                   numericInput(inputId = "AB","AB",1)),
            column(3,
                   numericInput(inputId = "A3","A",1))
          ),

          fluidRow(
            column(3,
                   numericInput(inputId = "B","C",1)),
            column(3,
                   numericInput(inputId = "AB3","AB",1))
          ),

          fluidRow(
            column(3,
                   numericInput(inputId = "B3","C",1)),
            column(3,
                   numericInput(inputId = "C23","C",1))
          )
        )
```

You can add more columns in 1 row  by adjusting the width of `column` and adding more inputs inside one `fluidRow`.